# How to split files up and process them in parallel and then stitch them back? unix

Tags: bash, perl, unix, split, cat

I have a text file `infile.txt` as such:

```
abc what's the foo bar.
foobar hello world, hhaha cluster spatio something something.
xyz trying to do this in parallel
kmeans you're mean, who's mean?
```

Each line in the file will be processed by this perl command into the out.txt

```
`cat infile.txt | perl dosomething > out.txt`
```

Imagine if the textfile is 100,000,000 lines. I want to parallelize the bash command so i tried something like this:

```
$ mkdir splitfiles
$ mkdir splitfiles_processed
$ cd splitfiles
$ split -n3 ../infile.txt
$ for i in $(ls); do "cat $i | perl dosomething > ../splitfiles_processed/$i &"; done
$ wait
$ cd ../splitfiles_processed
$ cat * > ../infile_processed.txt
```

But is there a less verbose way to do the same?

Comment: Why split it anyway? Also there's a `cat` abuse in there. `perl` can do the modifications in place, it can also make a backup copy.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What problem are you really trying to resolve that lead you to wanting to use this type of solution?

Comment: Treat the `cat ... | ... ` as a `# do something`. I need to split a file to process it in parts and then stitch the processed parts back into a single file. I have no control about the `#do something` so i feed it a textfile and it outputs a processed textfile.

Comment: You've got a working solution. You probably will not find a more simple implementation of MAP/REDUCE.  Eight lines of shell code is NOT a verbose solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer from @Ulfalizer gives you a good hint about the solution, but it lacks some details.

You can use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (`apt-get install parallel` on Debian)

So your problem can be solved using the following command:

```
cat infile.txt | parallel -l 1000 -j 10 -k --spreadstdin perl dosomething > result.txt
```

Here is the meaning of the arguments:

```
-l 1000: send 1000 lines blocks to command
-j 10: launch 10 jobs in parallel
-k: keep sequence of output
--spreadstdin: sends the above 1000 line block to the stdin of the command
```

Comment: definitely does not work. Proof: `parallel -a <(seq 5000) -l 1000 -j 10 -k --spreadstdin perl dosomething > result.txt` will 'hang'. While `seq 5  | parallel -a <(seq 5000) -l 1000 -j 10 -k --spreadstdin cat` will print 5 lines. So shown example does NOT read from file, it reads from stdin. If you specify --pipe/--spreadstdin it will read from stdin and -a is ignored.

Comment: Hello @MartinMucha There have been changes in the Parallel 20140422 version introducing the `pipepart` parameter which is a substitute for `pipe/spreadstdin` when input is read from files.

Comment: @Adam sure, but --pipe and --spreadstdin are still valid options. IIUC --pipepart just don't work with lines but blocks. I'm not aware that this should/could influence reading from pipe/file. If it does, could you please show full, executable command(which does not assume existence of any file etc)?

Comment: @MartinMucha You are answering a question posted in 2015 when parallel was working differently on the standard Debian version. Following those changes and your comment, I already updated my answer with a still working example. I also already explained you when this change was introduced. If you have question about the introduction of the `pipepart` parameter, you should open a new question, because it's not the subject here, but just the reason why the former example stopped working. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've never tried it myself, but [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) might be worth checking out.

Here's an excerpt from the man page (`parallel(1)`) that's similar to what you're currently doing. It can split the input in other ways too.

```
EXAMPLE: Processing a big file using more cores
       To process a big file or some output you can use --pipe to split up
       the data into blocks and pipe the blocks into the processing program.

       If the program is gzip -9 you can do:

       cat bigfile | parallel --pipe --recend '' -k gzip -9 >bigfile.gz

       This will split bigfile into blocks of 1 MB and pass that to gzip -9
       in parallel. One gzip will be run per CPU core. The output of gzip -9
       will be kept in order and saved to bigfile.gz
```

Whether this is worthwhile depends on how CPU-intensive your processing is. For simple scripts you'll spend most of the time shuffling data to and from the disk, and parallelizing won't get you much.

You can find some introductory videos by the GNU Parallel author [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your limiting factor is NOT your disk, you can do this in perl with `fork()` and specifically [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $max_forks = 8; #2x procs is usually optimal

sub process_line {
    #do something with this line
}

my $fork_manager = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( $max_forks ); 

open ( my $input, '<', 'infile.txt' ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    $fork_manager -> start and next;
    process_line ( $line );
    $fork_manager -> finish;
}

close ( $input );
$fork_manager -> wait_all_children();
```

The downside of doing something like this though is that of coalescing your output. Each parallel task doesn't *necessarily* finish in the sequence it started, so you have all sorts of potential problems regarding serialising the results.

You can work around these with something like `flock` but you need to be careful, as too many locking operations can take away your parallel advantage in the first place. (Hence my first statement - if your limiting factor is disk IO, then parallelism doesn't help very much at all anyway).

There's various possible solutions though - so much the wrote a whole chapter on it in the perl docs: [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) - but keep in mind you can retrieve data with [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#RETRIEVING-DATASTRUCTURES-from-child-processes) too.

Comment: I like Parallel::ForkManager, but not to process one line at at time.  Processing one shard of the file - yes, one line - no, too much fork orverhead.

Comment: It's replicating the request of the OP. But yes, it would rather depend on how much 'effort' is needed for each line. `fork` is quite lightweight though - and is what will be happening for e.g. any sort of gnu parallel style operation.

Comment: Fork is not lightweight. It is among the heaviest.

Comment: Heaviest what? Every process you invoke is a fork and exec. It is therefore quite well.optimised on Unix.

Comment: Every system has been around for decades, they still have relative costs, and fork/exec are among the highest which is why it's the first thing eliminated when optimising a web stack.